# How can I get the "value" section from a json using python?

Tags: python

So I need to get the "value" section from a json that should look something like this:

```
{
    "id": "<profile identifier>",
    "name": "<player name>",
    "properties": [ 
        {
            "name": "textures",
            "value": "<base64 string>",
            "signature": "<base64 string; signed data using Yggdrasil's private key>" // Only provided if ?unsigned=false is appended to url
        }
    ],
    "profileActions": []
}
```

My code currently looks like this, but i can't work out how to get the value because it is inside the properties section.

```
skin_url = "https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/profile/" + data['id'] + "?unsigned=false"
skin_r = requests.get(skin_url)
skin_data = json.loads(skin_r.text)
print(skin_data["properties"]["value"])
```

Anyone got any ideas?

This is the details of the error i got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myname\Python\numbers.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(skin_data["properties"]["value"])
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: `properties` is an `array`, so you must specify an index. Try `skin_data["properties"][0]["value"]`

Comment: @Benevos The value associated with the "properties" key is a *list* - not an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're encountering is because "properties" is a list, and you're trying to access it like a dictionary. You need to iterate through the list to access the "value" inside the "properties" list.

```
skin_url = "https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/profile/" + data['id'] + "?unsigned=false"
skin_r = requests.get(skin_url)
skin_data = json.loads(skin_r.text)

# Check if "properties" is not empty
if skin_data.get("properties"):
    # Iterate through the list of properties
    for prop in skin_data["properties"]:
        if prop.get("name") == "textures" and prop.get("value"):
            skin_value = prop["value"]
            print(skin_value)
else:
    print("No properties found in the JSON.")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the "properties" key exists then its value is expected to be a list. You will need to iterate over that list.

Always check the status after any HTTP method invocation (GET in this case).

Isolate your parameters from the URL.

The requests.models.Response object has a convenience function *json()*

Therefore:

```
import requests

data = {
    "id": "your id goes here"
}

url = "https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/profile/" + data["id"]
params = {
    "unsigned": "false"
}

with requests.get(url, params=params) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    skin_data = response.json()
    for p in skin_data.get("properties", []):
        print(p.get("value"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

> print(skin_data.get('properties')[0].get('value'))

Comment: This will fail miserably if the "properties" key is absent